# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-i18next' in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, internationalization, react-i18next

The console shows that it cannot resolve 'react-i18next' . When creating new files, the same error occurs.

I think the error may be related to an incorrect Webpack build. In the **buildPlugin.ts** project, it is placed in a separate file. Next, the general assembly takes place in **buildWebpackConfig.ts**

I don't want to update packages on principle.

```
package.json*
"devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.21",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/webpack": "^5.28.0",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-entities": "^2.4.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.5.3",
    "sass": "^1.49.9",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "ts-node": "^10.5.0",
    **"typescript": "^4.5.5",
    "webpack": "^5.69.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"**
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cross-fetch": "^4.0.0",
   ** "i18next": "^21.6.11",**
   ** "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.3",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.3.2",**
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    **"react-i18next": "^11.15.5",**
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1"
  }
```

*i18n.ts*

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

i18n
    .use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        debug: __IS_DEV__,

        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
        },

        backend: {
            loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
        }
    });


export default i18n;
```

*buildWebpackConfig.ts*

```
import {BuildOptions} from "./types/config";
import webpack from "webpack";
import {buildPlugins} from "./buildPlugins";
import {buildLoaders} from "./buildLoaders";
import {buildResolvers} from "./buildResolvers";
import {buildDevServer} from "./buildDevServer";

export function buildWebpackConfig(options: BuildOptions): webpack.Configuration {
    const {paths, mode, isDev} = options;

    return {
        mode,
        entry: paths.entry,
        output: {
            filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
            path: paths.build,
            clean: true
        },
       ** plugins: buildPlugins(options),**
        module: {
            rules: buildLoaders(options)
        },
        resolve: buildResolvers(options),
        devtool: isDev ? 'inline-source-map' : undefined,
        devServer: isDev ? buildDevServer(options) : undefined,
    }
}
```

*buildPlugin.ts*

```
import HTMLWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";
import webpack from "webpack";
import {BuildOptions} from "./types/config";
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";

export function buildPlugins({paths, isDev}: BuildOptions): webpack.WebpackPluginInstance[] {

    return [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: paths.html
        }),
        new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
            chunkFilename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css'
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __IS_DEV__: JSON.stringify(isDev),
        }),
    ]
}
```

I tried to update all packages to the latest version, but there are errors in index.d.ts. I tried to add something similar to buildPlugins.ts

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.AliasPlugin({
        alias: {
            "react-i18next": "react-i18next"
        }
    })
],
```